# Transactional method connection leak HikariCP jdbctemplate

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I experienced a weird issue. It happened only once for a long time living application. And I am trying to diagnose what was the problem.

First of all, the exception is

```
    [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: hikari_cp - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.] with root cause
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: hikari_cp - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

Above is happened for all db query threads. All of requests to db were failed. I guess according to exception message there was a connection leak? Can you confirm it? (Yes I will enable leak detection)

My second question is what can cause the connection leak? Please see the commented line below.

```
@Transactional
public SuccessfulLoginAttemptDto recordSuccessfulLogin(Login login) {
    Optional<Instant> optionalLastLoginTime = loginRepository.getLastSuccessfulLogin(login.getAccountId());
    authNotifierService.loginSuccess(login); //if this is hanging and keeps thread running, would it cause connection leak? Since because of the transactional annotation the connection is not closed until method returns. (this line does not call any db operation)  
    return smth;
}
```

Or maybe, can any long running query above cause connection leak? Like, all the connections are busy more than 30 seconds and incoming threads could not find available connection although they waited 30 seconds?

Edit:

```
@Override
public Optional<LoginAttempt> getLastSuccessfulLogin(Long accountId) {
    var params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue(PARAM_ACCOUNT_ID, accountId, Types.BIGINT);
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LAST_SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_ATTEMPT_EVENT,
                params, LoginAttempt.rowMapper));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return empty();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You expect an answer without actually seeing the code that is using JDBC? You only provide the high level service, without knowing what is happening in the actual repositories (the jdbc access) this is impossible to know.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is this related? Anyway, please see the edit. Thanks

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you need how I configured the data source?

Comment: I assume you are using the pre configured one from Spring Boot and only supplied properties in your `application.properties/yml` file. I also wonder what the `authNotifierService.loginSuccess` method actually does. Generally a connection leak occurs when one uses the datasource yourself to obtain a connection.

Comment: Yes, I'm just supplying props. Btw, I saw this line `var jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)` in the constructor of JDBCDao, is it concerning? JDBCDao is annotated with @Repository. 

Another is - loginSuccess method has several operations, one concerning is - it sends message via JMS, my guess is at that time jms was down and it was hung. - probably I did not receive ack and thread was still waiting then since the caller is transactional method it also kept connections occupied? Does it make sense?

Comment: Creating a `JdbcTemplate` isn't the culprit. A hanging transaction can be the culprit, you could set a timeout for the transaction so you don't run into this again.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. I believe I should set optimal value, right? Because by default it is 30 seconds. Seems this was too high to let other transactions get an available connection?

Comment: By default I believe there isn't a transaction timeout and it will wait indefinitly. A transaction timeout is something else as a connection timeout. The latter should be something you set as well (connection and read timeout) for both JDBC and JMS. You want to fail-fast rather than fail never (or very late).

Comment: That's clear. Thanks a lot @M.Deinum